# Where do i begin programming in php?

Tags: php, programming-languages, dreamweaver

i am a programer i have programed in C#, asp.net, Visual basic, Java, j2me, and now i want to learn php, i downloaded dreamweaver i choosed php
and i watch only code html i dont know how to put textbox, radiobutton, and more controls, in the another (not java) i choose the control and i move it... it is easy doing it, of this form, i didn't see nothing as this, in dreamweaver, another question, how do you add class in php? for a programing OO ...
add clases and methods (in php i believe they are called functions) 
if dreamweaver is bad, what program do you recommend me?

Comment: are you trying to ask for a good resource to learn PHP? The reason you're seeing just html in dreamweaver is that you can just insert portions of php in a larger html page OR can generate even that html from the php. I know people have numerous (and valid) problems with w3schools.com, but that's where I started learning php.

Comment: PHP is not designed to have a "drag-and-drop forms" interface. The other languages you're used to are somewhat unique in that respect (at least for web programming).

Comment: @angel, if you've ever used Visual Studio then I don't know how you can stand Dreamweaver, calling it a terrible IDE would be an understatement.

Comment: I asked this to my friend and he told it does have  a "drag-and-drop controls" i refert to textbox, buttons... may be he doesn't understand or me, i dont know, he is studying php, i am studing c#, .. .but i want to learn two languajes now

Comment: It has drag and drop html controls, but they aren't server controls in the same fashion that VS provides for webforms.

Comment: @angel: You can indeed add those kinds of controls, and you may be able to drag them into a page, and you may even be able to drag and move them around, but if you move them around, it's likely your IDE is using `position: absolute`, which is just kind of a pain because if you resize your browser window everything won't be re-layout in a nice way unless you use JavaScript and that just complicates things even more. In short, just write HTML; that's what it's going to be outputting anyway.

Comment: I dont think this question has to be closed. Despite the redundant nature of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use DreamWeaver for PHP development. But don't expect the same 'look and feel' of IDEs like MS C# or VB.

For example, you can create your forms in design view on DreamWeaver by dragging elements onto it, and then add the code by going into code-view. I don't recall the actual wording used on DreamWeaver but there's one view with a designer and the other with HTML code.

For example, if you create a textbox on the form, the code behind it will be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtEmployeeID" />
```

Now, if you want to print some variable from within the code, you could include it in the code view like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtEmployeeID" value="<?php echo $EmployeeID; ?>" />
```

You can actually incorporate PHP code within the html page simply by enclosing the code within the php tags like above.

But this is only a very elementary example. You can actually use ANY editor and what you use would also depend on the OS you have. For example, on Ubuntu I use GEdit, with a few plugins that help easily read PHP code using a nice colour scheme. But for a beginner, this may not be the ideal thing.

I don't mean to advertise myself, but I have a simple video of GEdit in use on YouTube. If you're interested, you may check it out on my channel "marhaonline".

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) is an IDE where it will assist you with functions...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: ***My recommendation is totally subjective***.

I recommend [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) (my personal preference over Eclipse for programming in PHP) or [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) + [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) for programming in [PHP](http://php.net/). I find those two to be the best `PHP IDE`'s (if someone is not agree, please, see the disclaimer).

About OOP in `PHP` you can read [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

In `PHP` we usually don't drag'n'drop controls since we don't have any "*Borland PHP Builders*". Usually it is done manually in pure `HTML`.

Comment: Methods can return values. The only difference between methods and functions are that methods are in a class. (also, perhaps ease up on the `backticks`)

Comment: I was mistaken about method definition. Thank you for correction.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation will be going with Zend Studio. It is developed especially for PHP Development, where as others, are created for multiple purposes.

Did I mentiond It is also an award winning IDE also?...
[Check Here](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/)

---

You are also asking about putting textbox, and radio buttons. This is more HTML based, rather than PHP, if this is major concern then, it should go with netbeans or dreamweaver, they provide better and user friendly UI for this.

In the latest dreamweaver, 
There is a panel called Insert Panel (Ctrl + F2 on Windows), it gives all the HTML elements, including form elements (Just select "FORM" from the drop down box"), which you can also drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

to begin php first u need to install apache, php, mysql 
u can get these as a group in wamp and xamp etc.
u can download it and install in ur mission thats it.

and next for php, mysql tutorials u can go for the sites 
http://www.w3schools.com/
or
http://www.tizag.com/

and learn javascript and ajax.

welcome to php. happy learning............

Answer (score 1):

I say use Notepad++ if you're on windows, GEdit if you're in Linux, or Textwranger on OS X. Learn to code without the visual, and you will be better off for OO, understand the coding, and move much quicker than drag-n-drop. There are many sites out there that has tutorials. tizag.com is one i like, they make the steps incrementally small and simple to learn from. And don't forget about php.net, they have tons and tons of contributed notes from hardcore programmers as well.